# Nodes vs shards on elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud

We know elastic needs to allocate computing resources for each availability zone.
(Either if those are actual (dedicated) nodes or shared resources which is unknown)

... so increasing availability zones may not only impact from the HA POV but also will effectively provide additional computing resources to the cluster.

Now the question is this:

Would make any sense to define 3 AZ having a 1 primary+1 replica index?

Since indexes are defined at Kibana and AZs are defined on the ES-cloud GUI
this is possible to do ... may it bring any improvement?

NOTE we are on a heavy searching cluster we want to optimize for searches.

Comment: What do you mean by "1 primary+1 replica **index**" ? Did you mean "1 primary+1 replica shard per index"?

Comment: @Val - yes, thats what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would make any sense to define 3 AZ having a 1 primary+1 replica index?

Absolutely! You're giving the cluster more headroom for self-balancing
(in case you got more than 1 index, indeed).

Then, many factors actually kick in: the nature of your data, your retention policies, how resource-greedy your ingest pipelines are, etc.

To have really well balanced & optimized cluster you'd have to take this into account after you pass certain point in your growth, but generally speaking - that's the main advantage.

> Since indexes are defined at Kibana

Huh?
No, they are not - only index patterns are.

To either define or use the index Kibana is 100% optional.

Comment: My bad ... only index patterns are dined in kibana. You are right.

Comment: Exactly. So BECAUSE rollover will create more indexes the primary/replicas of those new indexed may be relocated to the 3rd AZ computing resources. I can assume that INITIALLY that computing resources will be mostly idle until that happens then. Right?

Comment: I bet they would be underloaded initially, let's put it this way.
You can also look at autoscaling option for your cluster deployment available with recent versions. But I must admit I didn't work with it. Yet.